# cin в условии с объявлением переменой

Tags: c++

новичок в c++. При чтении гугловского стайлгайда увидел объявление переменных в условиях:

```
while (const char* p = strchr(str, '/')) str = p + 1;
```

и теперь задаюсь вопросом как к такому виду можно привести такой код:

```
int a;
while (std::cin >> a) {
    ...
}
```

Первой мыслю было сделать что-то вроде такого, но оно не сработало:

```
while (std::cin >> int a) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `if` можно так: `if (int a; std::cin >> a)`.

В `while` это не работает (в условии там нельзя писать `;`), поэтому скорее всего никак нельзя.

Можно использовать `for`, вот так: `for (int a; std::cin >> a;)`

Comment: А как такое можно объединить с условием, допустим a != 0?

Comment: @СашаВолотко `std::cin >> a && a != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

С чистым `std::cin` вы вряд ли сможете сделать нечто подобное. Однако у вас всегда есть `std::cin::get()`, который возвращает один или несколько символов из потока ввода. И его можно использовать вот так:

```
while(char c = std::cin.get()) {
    // Выведет посимвольно весь текст из потока ввода
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

// Или так
char c;
while(std::cin.get(c)) {
    // Выведет посимвольно весь текст из потока ввода
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Данный метод немного отличается от действия самого `std::cin` и его оператора `>>`, однако у него есть свои преимущества. Стоит помнить, что get() считывает лишь один символ, либо указанное в параметрах количество символов, а `std::cin >>` все, вплоть до первого пробела.

**Важно:**

Помните, что get возвращает код символа, который считал из потока ввода. Это означает, что если вы хотите считать int, то в int будут преобразовываться даже символы, согласно их кодам ASCII:

```
// При вводе Hello выведет:
//72 101 108 108 111 10
while(int i = std::cin.get()) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

`std::cin >>` же от таких случаев застрахован посредством входа в состояние отказа. Подробнее можно почитать в документации на cppreference. Так что вам нужно выбирать тот способ, который вам подойдет лучше

Comment: А как такое можно объединить с условием, допустим a != 0?

Comment: @СашаВолотко Красиво и внутри условия while - никак. Для этого придется использовать второй вариант записи, где `char c` объявляется до входа в цикл и писать `std::cin.get(c) && c != "H"`. Но с int это не сработает, нужно будет кастовать char к int и наоборот, это костыль и прямой путь к ошибкам. Куда проще внутрь цикла пихнуть if () и использовать первый вариант записи. Либо используйте for(), как советовали выше, но как по мне while с if внутри цикла, а не внутри условия смотрится куда лучше и понятнее. Да и ошибиться негде